# Why was the following question removed from ELU?

Tags: support

The following  question asks for the correct expression to use for a specific case of plagiarism:

> - [Is it plagiarism when copying something that you have written before?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68176/is-it-plagiarism-when-copying-something-that-you-have-written-before)

and though it got a correct answer on ELU, it was removed and migrated to another site.

The question is essentially about an English term and its usage and OP is not asking about  possible  implications of "self-plagiarism". Moreover, the  answers given in the other site don't seem to add much to the answer given on ELU.

On what grounds was the question removed?

Edit: ***the whole issue appears to be based on my misunderstanding of the question, sorry for that.***

Comment: I think it should have been migrated to [Law beta Stack Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions). It is not an easy question for non-experts to answer.

Comment: @Rathony The Powers That Be have decided to prohibit migration  paths to beta sites, so they have time to work out their scope without any external influence. Until it graduates, it's not even technically possible to set up a migration path to Law, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rathony It's not a Law question, because there is no law against self-plagiarism. It's an Academia question, because institutions do have rules about re-submitting one's own material.

Answer (score 6):

It was moved because the question is **not** "essentially about an English term", nor does it ask "for the correct expression to use for a specific case of plagiarism":

> I am writing an essay and I have previously written and submitted an essay to a different professor about a similar subject. Would it be considered plagiarism if I copied my own exact sentences from my previous essay?

The OP is asking whether an academic institution would consider the practice of self-copying plagiarism. He is not asking whether there is such a term as *self-plagiarism*. The question as asked is better asked of a community of academics.

It's worth pointing out that the question has gained a number of upvotes following its migration.

Comment: I left a comment asking the OP if he were an undergraduate, and then suggesting he visit academia, but it would seem pretty excessive for a teenager who hasn't done his homework. The OP didn't reply, and my longish comment has been deleted. Why are comments asking for clarification deleted when questions are migrated to different sites?What happened to Josh's answer? I know if he doesn't have an account on that site his avatar is greyed, but shouldn't the answer still be isible? Did he self-delete his answer? Not saying that the answer would be appropriate for academia but...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Comments containing links to another SE site are automagically deleted if the question is migrated there (applies to both your comments). I don't the rationale behind that; while it may work well with migration comments, it's not appropriate to every comment. Josh61's answer went with the question, but I can't see deleted answers on Academia.

Comment: It does seem a waste to delete comments from users that help those who want to answer the OP's migrated question. Well, thank you for replying.